# Text disappearing when rotating tab component in Openlaszlo's SWF runtime

Tags: text, tabs, rotation, openlaszlo, lzx

Why when I apply a rotation tab text disappears of the tabs? Is there any way to keep the labels in its relative position, so it rotate along with the tab?

code:

```
<tabs name="dentes" height="200"  width="300" x="${this.width}" y="${this.height}" rotation="90">
    <tabpane name="coroa" text="Coroa" bgcolor="blue" width="100%" height="100%"> 
        <text>Nome:</text>
    </tabpane>
    <tabpane name="raiz" text="Raiz" bgcolor="red" width="100%" height="100%"> 
        <text>Nome:</text>
    </tabpane>
    <tabpane name="canal" text="Canal" bgcolor="green" width="100%" height="100%"> 
        <text>Nome:</text>
    </tabpane>
</tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a technical limitation of the Flash/SWF runtime when using client fonts. It's mentioned in the docs as well:

> [OpenLaszlo Developers Guide, Chapter 21, Text Views](http://labs.openlaszlo.org/trunk-nightly/docs/developers/text.html):   In
>   particular, you should understand the difference between client fonts
>   and embedded fonts in applications compiled to SWF. (Applications
>   compiled to DHTML cannot use embedded fonts). Because they don't
>   always behave the same way (for example client fonts can not be
>   rotated or changed in opacity due to a limitation of the Flash Player)

Use the `<font>` tag to embed TTF fonts into your application. If you select that font for your text, the rotatoin will work as expected, e.g.:

```
<canvas width="100%" height="250">

    <!-- ATTENTION: Please download the KentucyFriedChickendFont.ttf file using
         this URL and put it in the same folder as this LZX file.
         http://svn.openlaszlo.org/openlaszlo/trunk/test/resources/ttf/KentuckyFriedChickenFont.ttf
    -->

    <font name="ChickenNoCFF" src="KentuckyFriedChickenFont.ttf" embedascff="false" />
    <font name="ChickenCFF" src="KentuckyFriedChickenFont.ttf" embedascff="true" />

    <inputtext x="100" 
               rotation="10"
               font="ChickenNoCFF" fontsize="32" 
               hasdirectionallayout="false"
               resize="true">
    Embedded font (no CFF)
    </inputtext>

    <!-- Text elements using @hasdirectionallayout="true" need to set
         @embedascff="true" for the SWF10+ runtimes -->
    <inputtext x="100" y="100"
               rotation="10" 
               font="ChickenCFF" fontsize="32" 
               hasdirectionallayout="true">
    Embedded font (embedded as CFF)
    </inputtext>

</canvas>
```

You have to embed the TTF fonts into your application, and then you are free to rotate any standard text component.

If you use the `hasdirectionallayout` property of text components in SWF applications, you have to use the `embedascff="true"` attribute when embedding custom fonts.

Here's a screenshot of this example SWF10 app, tested on 5.0 (trunk).

[image]